# How to get DbContext class in EF Core without bringing in EF 6?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

EDIT:

I'm having a problem because Package Manager complains that "Entity Framework 6.x and Entity Framework Core commands are installed."  But I don't think it's coming from the EntityFrameworkCore NuGet package.  I have a website project which uses DbContext.  It gets it from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App package (the ONLY NuGet package it loads), and the website project only use the EF Core commands installed.  I tried using that package in my library project, and I still get the same problem.  So my problem is apparently not coming from the NuGet package.

More investigation is apparently in order...

---

Original question:

I'm migrating library code from .NET 4.6.2 to .NET Core 2.1.  This code has references to `DbContext` (in `System.Data.Entity`).  In order to pull in an equivalent .NET Core `DbContext` (in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`), I can load the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` NuGet package.  The problem is that that package apparently brings in EF6 in addition to EF Core, so when I try to issue an `update-database` command in the Package Manager Console, it complains that "Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed".

Presumably, I can figure out a Package Manager command that works around this annoyance, but I have no (obvious) need for EF 6 and I would just as soon figure out how to bring in `DbContext` WITHOUT bringing in EF 6.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I looked at the csproj file, and there was an extraneous line, apparently left over from earlier fiddling with NuGet packages:

```
<PackageReference
    Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"
    Version="2.1.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

Since there is no reason for this library to deal with web code generation, I removed that line from the csproj file, and now the message about having EF 6 tools loaded has magically gone away.  Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

> This code has references to `DbContext` (in `System.Data.Entity`)

That seems to be your problem. Throw it away.

The correct `DbContext` lives in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace, from the same nuget package.

Probably you should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/):

- [Code First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-code)
- [DB First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx)

Make sure you have the old nuget package uninstalled.

[image: Nuget]